# How to fetch all documents with a certain value in an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So basically I need to fetch all documents that has a particular value inside a certain array within that document. I have been led to believe that $in is the correct operator for such a method but so far mongo has refused to return any value at all from my code. I've tried many different methods to no avail. Here's the function that I'm currently running for it.

```
exports = async function(payload, response) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    
    const query = payload.query 
    const mongodb = await context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
    const Lobbies = await mongodb.db("Sword_Universe").collection("Lobbies");
    const playerLobbies = JSON.stringify(Lobbies.find( { "players" : { $in: ["serverOptimist"] } } ))
    console.log(playerLobbies);
    response.setBody(playerLobbies);
};
```

Comment: Can you share more about what are you expecting to be the data model for Lobbies and its players field?

Comment: Basically the  data model for lobbies is expected to create a blank players field. When a player calls the api they are automatically added to all lobbies the player is able to join. If there are no such lobbies, it just creates an entirely new lobby all together. Every (X) amount of seconds, typically not too long cause I want it to be relatively fast. I want the api to fetch all documents where the player is currently in the "players" array essentially is the end goal.

Comment: Now it searches the Lobbies that have players-array that has an element that equals to string of "serverOptimist". Should you use some value from request to find the player that is doing the query?

Comment: Yes, that is correct currently. This was merely put in place just to test it. I do have a playerName in the query but at the moment I have refrained from adding it. I can confirm however that "serverOptimist" is always in 1 document that I have checked over countless times.

Comment: So the players in in Lobbies is an array that contains strings or the full player object with name field?

Comment: The player is meant to be in the array that contains the player's name, which is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the players list is a list of player objects with name field the query should be

`players:{$elemMatch:{name:"serverOptimist"}}`

Edit: and as it's search by just [single field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#std-label-elemmatch-single-query-condition) it can be shorten

`"players.name":"serverOptimist"`

If it's a string array of player names simply this should work:

`"players":"serverOptimist"`

Comment: elemMatch has also been a method I've tried to no avail, just revisited the method and didn't return anything but a blank array.  I even tried making an object and adding a "name" to the object but again, never worked.  I was told $in would help as well but so far it has not.

Comment: can you share what Lobbies.find({}) returns? as I think there is still some misunderstanding of the expected data model.

Comment: Lobbies.find() will return all the documents with their respective "players" array.  The "players" array will have all the player names inside of them. If the player in question's name is in that array(Which will be a string), I want the entire document to be returned.

Comment: Then the last one of those examples and your original code should work I think.

Comment: Hey sorry about the late response, this is what I'm currently doing but it doesn't seem to work. 

const playerLobbies = JSON.stringify(Lobbies.find( {players:"serverOptimist"} ))